# Game Center Simultaneous Turns

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, xcode, game-center

I'm new to iOS (although I do have a lot of C++ experience) and I am working on a turn-based card game using gamecenter. Here's the catch - The player who's turn it is is the judge and waits for all OTHER players to play a card before the turn is over. Is there a way to do this in Game Center, so all players chose what to do simultaneously and once all have done so, the judge is notified, makes a decision, and then passes priority to the next player? For example, say we start turn 1. I ask the question, @"What is your favorite color?" to all players passing them a gamestate which has that as the question and them not having answered it. Then you respond, @"Green", and our friend Steve responds @"Blue". I then decide which is better, give one of you a point, and then whoever I gave the point becomes the new judge. My question is, how do I allow all players to respond simultaneously, rather than sequentially. I know that, worst case, I could sequentially loop around through players until it comes back to me, then judge it, but this would slow down my game and make it less fun. Is there a way to do this simultaneously?

Comment: If you notify the judge player as soon as a choice is made by any player, then code running on the judges side should easily know if they got all responses or not. Right?

Answer (score 1):

The iOS API is built around the model of sequential turns. While the workaround you mentioned will work, there is no way to get GC to do *real* concurrent turns. Sorry ):

Comment: As an extension to this, as of iOS7 this is possible via exchanges - a mechanism that allows players who aren't the current player to transmit data to other players and update the match state.

Answer (score 1):

I agree with NSSplendid about the API for turnbased games requiring sequential turns.  The only truly simultaneous method would be using the real-time matches from GKMatch, and that isn't really an option for games with more than a few players.

However, the sequential version could be improved slightly by using a programmatic approach to game center instead of the default view controller.

Ending a turn fires off a push notification through Game Center, and by using GKTurnBasedEventHandler's method handleTurnEventForMatch:didBecomeActive:, you can receive that in your app.  When the judge asks the question, have the users display that as part of the game, and have their responses stored locally until their turn.  Once it becomes a given player's turn, they receive the notification, even with the app in the background.

In the method, it can check the locally stored answer and end the turn immediately, if they've answered.  If they haven't, send the turn once the answer is complete.  It's not truly simultaneous, but the judge gets the answers as soon as everyone has responded, without the players having to wait for one player to finish before they can enter their own answers.

The players won't get the notification that the judge has ended their turn until they open the app, but they can't see the question anyways without doing that.  Another approach to this, though slightly wasteful, is after the judge ends their turn with their question, is to do a runthrough of all the players ending their turn as soon as they get the "Your turn" notification, so everyone knows a question has been asked, then doing the steps from the previous two paragraphs.